# How to handle a PostMessageThread message in std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, stdthread

Somewhere in my *main thread* I am calling `PostThreadMessage()`. But I don't know how to handle it in the `std::thread` I have sent it to.

I am trying to handle it in `std::thread` like this:

```
while(true) {
    if(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        // Doing appropriate stuff after receiving the message.
    }
}
```

And I am sending the message from the main thread like this:

```
PostThreadMessage(thread.native_handle(), WM_CUSTOM_MESSAGE, 0, 0);
```

I don't know if I am supposed to receive the message as I did in my thread.

All I want to know is, how to check whether the *"worker thread"* is receiving the message I am sending it.

Comment: `if (GetMessage(...)) { if (msg.message == WM_CUSTOM_MESSAGE) { // got it! } }`. But you can't pass `native_handle()` to `PostThreadMessage` - it wants an ID, not a handle. Use `PostThreadMessage(GetThreadId(thread.native_handle()), ...)`.

Comment: Its not working even when I do that. I am using a gcc compiler. And `GetMessage` is not even catching any message.

Comment: @AmritSanjeev Microsoft's implementation of `std::thread::native_handle()` returns the Win32 `HANDLE` of the thread. There is no guarantee that is what gcc's implementation of `std::thread::native_handle()` returns.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The compiler did say something about `std::thread::native_handle` is returning an `unsigned long long int`. *(When there was a type conversion error.)*

Comment: @AmritSanjeev `native_handle()` returns an *implementation-defined* type. You can't make any assumptions about what `native_handle()` actually returns, unless you look at the source/docs for the *specific* implementation you are using. And in this case, there is no guarantee that gcc's implementation is even using a Win32 thread to begin with. It could be using the pthread library instead, for instance.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok, If I do manage to figure out how to send the message to the thread, am I handing it correctly?

Comment: Since gcc comes from the POSIX world, odds are someone's implemented pthreads (POSIX threads) over top of win32 threads to keep the code as similar as possible. You're probably getting a pthread-style thread handle that refers to a win32 thread handle, not a direct win32 thread handle.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes it could be using the pthread library, and that would in turn be using a native OS thread.  `native_handle()` needs to return a native OS handle, not internal data specific to a helper library (like pthreads-win32)

Comment: @user4581301 So how would I get said "direct win32 handle"?

Comment: @user4581301: The function isn't named `my_threading_helper_library_handle()` but `native_handle()`.  Any design that doesn't return an OS handle is pretty broken.

Comment: Looks pretty broken by that definition. `native_handle_type` is defined as `using native_handle_type = __gthread_t;` where `__gthread_t` is `typedef pthread_t __gthread_t;`

Comment: @BenVoigt "*`native_handle()` needs to return a native OS handle*" - that is incorrect. It needs to return the implementation's underlying thread representation. That does not need to be a handle to an OS thread, if that is not what the implementation uses (or even has access to). Remember, std::thread is defined by the C++ standard, which doesn't address specific OSes. In fact, the standard merely says: "*Several classes described in this Clause have members native_­handle_­type and native_­handle.
The presence of these members and their semantics is implementation-defined.*"

Comment: @AmritSanjeev "*Ok, If I do manage to figure out how to send the message to the thread, am I handing it correctly?*" - yes, you are.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I tested it just now. Thank you!

Comment: For reference: [**thread.req.native**](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.native)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, it's a "quality of implementation" issue, not a conformity issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `std::thread::native_handle()` returns is *implementation-defined* (per [[thread.req.native]](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.native) in the C++ standard). There is no guarantee that it even returns a *thread ID* that `PostThreadMessage()` wants.

For instance, MSVC's implementation of `std::thread` uses `CreateThread()` internally, where `native_handle()` returns a Win32 `HANDLE`. You would have to use `GetThreadId()` to get the thread ID from that handle.

Other implementations of `std::thread` might not use `CreateThread()` at all. For instance, they could use the `pthreads` library instead, where `native_handle()` would return a `pthread_t` handle, which is not compatible with Win32 APIs.

A safer way to approach this issue is to not use `native_handle()` at all.  Call `GetCurrentThreadId()` inside of your thread function itself, saving the result to a variable that you can then use with `PostThreadMessage()` when needed, for example:

```
struct threadInfo
{
    DWORD id;
    std::condition_variable hasId;
};

void threadFunc(threadInfo &info)
{
    info.id = GetCurrentThreadId();
    info.hasId.notify_one();

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        // Doing appropriate stuff after receiving the message.
    }
}

...

threadInfo info;
std::thread t(threadFunc, std::ref(info));
info.hasId.wait();
...
PostThreadMessage(info.id, WM_CUSTOM_MESSAGE, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Wow, saving the thread id as a variable why didn't I think of that. Anyway thank you soooo very much. I have been searching for this answer for almost 2 days now. Your answer was a godsend. Again thank you so much!